# Pleiades eclipseの日本語化機能を無効にする方法

Tags: java, eclipse

Pleiades eclipseの日本語化機能の処理は遅いので、下記の方法で無効にしましたが、
もっときれいな方法ありますか？

１．eclipse.ini内のMergeDocのPluginをコメントアウト　（行先頭”＃”追記）
２．pluginのディレクトリ内で、MergeDocのディレクトリをリネーム
３．Eclipseを再起動

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse からアンインストール (英語に戻す)
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

Pleiades を無効にしたい場合は eclipse.ini 内の以下の 2 行の先頭に # を付けてコメントアウトするか行を削除してください。

```
  -Xverify:none
  -javaagent:〜/pleiades.jar
```

完全にアンインストールする場合は、上記 2 行削除に加え、以下のディレクトリを削除してください。(All in One の場合、plugins と features は dropins/MergeDoc/ にあります)

```
 plugins/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades/
 features/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades/
 (Pleiades キャッシュ・ディレクトリ)
```

(Pleiades キャッシュ・ディレクトリ) には Pleiades の構成やログが出力されます。Windows の場合、デフォルトでは (ECLIPSE_HOME)/configuration/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades です。
   書き込み権限が無い場合は下記が使用されます。

```
 <ユーザーホーム>/.pleiades/<インストールパスのハイフン区切り>/
```

ただし、Eclipse の config.ini に osgi.configuration.area が指定されている場合は、それが優先されます。IDEA で plugins ディレクトリに書き込み権がある場合は、以下が (Pleiades キャッシュ・ディレクトリ) になります。

```
 plugins/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades/cache
```

---

この内容は下記の readme に記載されています。
https://osdn.net/projects/mergedoc/scm/svn/blobs/head/trunk/Pleiades/readme/readme_pleiades.txt